# Copy file from mac to windows system 32

Tags: windows, bash, makefile

I've gnu make file on windows which needs to copy binary from `path` **a** to `path` **b**

I use the following

`sudo cp $(CURDIR)/build/$mybin C:\WINDOWS\system32`

and I got error

file not found , what am I missing here ?

Comment: You are missing... a file! It looks like the file you are trying to copy does not exist. Check for existence of `$(CURDIR)/build/$mybin`.

Comment: @Poshi - the file is exist of course :)

Comment: `cp` does not agree with you...

Comment: @Poshi - should my command  works also with windows ?

Comment: The copy? Yes. The sudo? Not sure. Try to run sudo alone (or with another non-failing command, like `sudo ls`) and see if the error persists. In that case, it would be the sudo. But the error message you say have more relation with cp than with sudo.

Comment: In make files, macro names should be surrounded by parentheses or braces, so `$mybin` should be `$(mybin)`.